# React input caret jumps to end if value gets modified

Tags: reactjs, react-state

input caret jumps to end if value gets transformed

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-caret-problem-8fkxqw?file=/src/App.js

Here I modify the value to uppercase before setting it as state

steps to reproduce:

1. Type "asd"
2. Move the caret after the "a" letter, or somewhere in the middle
3. Type something
4. It moves the caret to the end, after the "d" letter

**Why this happens and how can be fixed?**

Something interesting is that even if I delay the setting state via setTimeout, the caret moves to end before calling the callback from setTimeout.

With something like this . First it moves the caret then after 2 seconds it logs "change". That means it moves to right before setting the state. So strange...

```
  onChange={(event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('change')
      setV(value?.toUpperCase() || "")
    
    }, 2000)
  }}
```

Comment: What are you trieng to accomplish? I dealt with similar problemsin the past, and the solution depends on what you actually want to solve.

Comment: I was trying to understand why this happens, now I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `v` is not the actual value that is entered inside the input it will *replace* the value with the updated `v`. And thus move the cursor to the end.

When you type `a` the `toUpperCase()` will change it to `A`. So the value typed in the input is `a` once the state cycle has updated it will be `A`. It can just update a single letter, it will change the value with the new value. Emphasis on **new** since it differs from what originally is typed in the input.

**If you type a letter with `shift+{letter}`, the letter is already uppercase and the cursor will not shift to the end.**

I hope this explains the reason behind the **actual value** and the **value you type in**.

You can solve this by using a extra state to track the `cursorPosition` and when the value of the input changes you can set the cursor position back to its original place.

```js
const [v, setV] = React.useState("");
const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = React.useState(0);
const ref = React.useRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!ref.current) return;
  ref.current.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
}, [v]);

return (
  <input
    value={v}
    onChange={(event) => {
      const value = event.target.value;

      const selectionStart = event.target.selectionStart;
      setCursorPosition(selectionStart);
      setV(value?.toUpperCase());
    }}
    ref={ref}
  />
);
```

Comment: My first question was about MUI, I deleted it because i tought that MUI was causing the problem, but then I found out that react is the one causing trouble here. Text transform is not the answer I am looking for. I am trying to understand why it happens and also I might want to modify it differently, not with uppercase

Comment: What means "v is not the actual value" ? Since it is controlled, I should be the one telling him what its value is, not something else.

Comment: I've updated my answer @OktayYuzcan let me know if you understand the part about the *actual value*!

Comment: I saw few solutions like this one, but I just didn't want to believe that I need to do that much work just to update 1 value. Still can't believe it... all that code just to update single value... There is still things I don't get. Since it is controlled input, am I not the one to tell him what the value will be. Why it confuces it with the thing that I typed. My understanding of controlled inputs were that this is the value I give him, It should not care where it comes from.

Comment: I figured it out. It is not react problem, it is just how modified input values work. When the value gets transformed it loses the track of the caret, so it moves to the end. I will wait a bit if there are better ideas to solve this issue